# How to add svg markers in GMap.NET?

Tags: c#, google-maps, svg

In javascript version, you can write it like this:

```
var marker = new SVGMarker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.282788, -97.731457),
  icon: {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30.26),
    size: new google.maps.Size(60,30.26),
    url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/134893/pin-red.svg'
  }
})
```

or

```
var icon = {

    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: 1
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon
});
```

But how to use it in c#?

And GMarkerGoogle class just provider System.Drawing.Bitmap for Constructor Arguements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMap.Net GMapMarker's Shape Property is a wpf UIElement